# netbeans doesnt read .bashrc from remote machine ( linux) which is required for compile

Tags: linux, windows, compilation, environment-variables, netbeans-8

I have two box:

```
A- local machine, windows 7 : netbeans 8.01.
B- remote server, Linux REHL 6, connection : SSH
```

I am working in A on a C++ project (Makefile project) and i want to make it  by B's Compiler .
but I have to run "source ~/.bashrc" before make command in netbeans,

how to do it?

that replacement the make command  with

```
source ~/.bashrc  &&  /usr/bin/make
```

doesn't work and  add variables to project properties --> run --> environment variable doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for any shell that we get it from kernel, locally or remotely, bashrc, run automatically, so ,as i review .bashrc, again, its a problem related to a line of .bashrc file no Netbeans ,that solved finally